# Optimizing performance by saving data in local database

Tags: java, architecture

We are creating a financial transaction system. There is a blacklist service (soap) exposed by some external system. We have to call this service in each transaction to check whether the sender or receiver exist in black list. If they do we should not let the transaction through.
Black list size is a few thousand.

To optimize the system, we are thinking to keep a copy of this list in our database and check it from there and whenever there is an update in the blacklist external system will inform us.

From architecture point of view, is it a good approach? Should we use caching libraries instead of doing this manually?

Application is being developed in Java with Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you shouldn't invent the wheel, always use known libraries instead writing your own code since it probably more optimized and maintained.
If you are able to save the data on your local db and be inform somehow about changes in the external system it can be a better approach. 
Just be sure to synchronized your actions since you would probably want for the action that checked if someone is blacklisted to wait for the action that synchronized the data from the blacklist system in order to have the most updated data.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can (or not) be a good approach.

1) That SOAP in general means a webservice and that in general means latency. Do you want all step in your process to wait for that call to return?

2) That list maybe don't changes fast? Meaning it ill not hurt to keep that in "cache". You can tune the periodicity you system checks and updates your cache.

3) That SOAP also means an asynch call (in general) you can keep your system running while the "cache" is updated.

If you system is hot processing a lot and needs that to check that list many times/second and that list don't change 0.1% per day you ill be fine.

In the other hand if you system just run a batch a few times a day and that list is changing a lot every second it ill be not the best approach.